i18next replace jsx components but globally?
ho i can replace jsx tags with i18next globaly ?
i know ho replace tags like {{}}
i18next.use<PostProcessorModule>({
    type: 'postProcessor',
    name: POST_PROCESSORS.game,
    process( value, key, options, translator ) {
        return value.replace( /{{GAME_TITLE}}/g, GAME_TITLE );
    }
});

but how for jsx value ? 

// how use global replace balise like <x></x>
i18next.use({
    type: 'postProcessor',
    name: POST_PROCESSORS.components,
});

example if i want this globally:
        <Trans
            components={{ t: <a title={'xxxx'} /> }}
            i18nKey={'main:pages.game.introspection'}
        />

So i want replace  by a component link with title and the value used as id.
but not in every module ! juste one time
